# I need database that works on windows, sync data fast and has PHP api

Tags: database

I need to select a database engine, SQL or NOSQL doesn't matter as long as it easy to install and configure on windows,

the database will be used as application database on four workstations, it should sync data between those workstations, the problem is that any workstation could be shut down any moment and the rest should continues to work fine, also once dead database come back to life it should re-sync whatever it missed.

Another thing is that am writing application using php, so database should have php api or http interface to work with.

So far I have managed to build cassandra cluster, I was told it has good "failover mechanism" and "master to master" but when I took primary workstation the rest stopped working.

Its API need php with APC, the provided php windows binary by php.net doesn't have APC and could't find a library that doesn't depends on this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for how easy it is to synchronize multiple databases, but XAMPP ( http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html ) is the quickest way I've found to get PHP, database, and web services on a machine - it installs them all together as a single bundle.